# Setting dataTransfer.dropEffect has no effect on IE9

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, internet-explorer-9

Setting the *dataTransfer.dropEffect* in *dragEnter* and *dragOver* handlers does not seem to work in **Internet Explorer 9**.
Whatever the value, the cursor seems determined only by the *dataTransfer.effectAllowed* value set during *dragStart*.

In the example below, you will get a "copy" cursor (arrow with plus) by selecting and dragging "DRAG ME" both over "MOVE" or "COPY" in IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/aHDWL/

```
function fnDragOnDefault()
{
  var oEvent = window.event;
  oEvent.returnValue = false;

  var oData = window.event.dataTransfer;
  oData.dropEffect = "move";
}
```

If you switch back to **IE8 Document mode** (you can use F12 for that), then the **dropEffect setting will work** and the cursor will be different on the two boxes.

Is there any fix/workaround ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you made any progress on this problem?

Comment: Still could find no solution or workaround. **Even if you use dropEffect & effectAllowed together as suggested by some it doesn't work.** Once you set the icon in dragStart event it cannot be changed. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goodies4uall/sdftot4v/10/) for example. This is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780585/dropeffect-not-working-properly-in-ie-standard-mode-ie9-ie10) in IE reported 3 years ago that was closed with no solution or workaround.